# How to minimize chi squared for 3 linear fits

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, curve-fitting, chi-squared

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# This is my data set
x = [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 195, 210, 225, 240]
y = [1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.55, 0.5, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35, 0.33, 0.31, 0.29, 0.27, 0.25, 0.23]
```

I want to add 3 linear regressions to this data set.  By graphing my data set with pyplot I can visually see where kinks start to form ( at about x = 105, and x = 165).  And so I can create 3 linear regressions (from x is 0 to 105, 105 to165, and 165 to 240).  But how would I do this scientifically?  In other words, I want to add 3 linear regressions to my data that will minimize chi squared.  Is there a way to accomplish this with code?

Comment: I do not get what you want to achieve. Do you want to get three different parameter sets (one for each linear regression)?

Comment: I know how to create 3 separate linear fits for my data and calculate there respective chi squared values, but I do this simply by splitting my x,y lists.  I want to create an algorithm that will split the lists for me so that chi squared is minimized for all 3 linear fits.

Comment: I updated my answer; it now splits x and y automatically and I also added some more details on the for-loop. Let me know whether you have any further questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can find the code and output for an automated procedure using [scipy.stats.linregress](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html); explanation can be found below the code. The output looks as follows:

[image]

The slopes and interception terms are:

- curve 1: -0.0066 * x + 1.10
- curve 2: -0.0033 * x + 0.85
- curve 3: -0.0013 * x + 0.55

Here is the code:

```
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 195, 210, 225, 240])
y = np.array([1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.55, 0.5, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35, 0.33, 0.31, 0.29, 0.27, 0.25, 0.23])

# get slope of your data
dif = np.diff(y) / np.diff(x)

# determine the change of the slope
difdif = np.diff(dif)

# define a threshold for the allowed change of the slope
threshold = 0.001

# get indices where the diff returns value larger than a threshold
indNZ = np.where(abs(difdif) > threshold)[0]

# this makes plotting easier and avoids a couple of if clauses
indNZ += 1
indNZ = np.append(indNZ, len(x))
indNZ = np.insert(indNZ, 0, 0)

# plot the data
plt.scatter(x, y)

for indi, ind in enumerate(indNZ):

    if ind < len(x):
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x[ind:indNZ[indi+1]], y[ind:indNZ[indi+1]])
        plt.plot(x[ind:indNZ[indi+1]], slope * x[ind:indNZ[indi+1]] + intercept)

plt.show()
```

First, one can calculate the the slope using `np.diff`. Applying `np.diff` to the slope gives you the points where the slope changes significantly; in the code above I used a threshold for that (if you always deal with perfect lines than this could be set to a very small value; if you have noisy data, you will have to adjust this value).

Having the indices where the slope changes significantly, one can then do a linear regression in the respective sections and plot the results accordingly.

The for-loop in more detail:

```
indNZ
```

is

```
array([ 0,  4,  9, 16])
```

which gives you the intervals of your three lines. So the blue line corresponds to the section from `x[0]` and `x[3]`, the green line to the section from `x[4]` to `x[8]` and the red line to the section from `x[9]` to `x[15]`. In the for-loop, these ranges are selected, a linear fit is done using `scipy.stats.linregress` (which could also be replaced by `polyfit` if you like that more) and the line is then plotted using the equation `slope * x + intercept`.

Comment: Sorry, my question may not have been very clear.  I don't want to choose the range for my 3 linear fits.  I wanted to create an algorithm that would do this for me.  For instance, say if I incorrectly chose the x ranges to be 0 to 100, 100 to 200, and 200 to 240.  The chi squared value for this range would be too large.  I would like the algorithm to find the 3 ranges that would minimize chi squared.  I sort of have an idea of how to do this, but it is way too complicated for me to implement.  Thanks for trying though!

Comment: I updated the code. Please let me know whether that now solves the problem or whether it needs to be revised.

Comment: I'm not familiar with stats.linregress.  I use the polyfit to create linear fits.   Can you please explain what you were doing in the for loop?  Thanks!

Comment: @PiccolMan: I added a few more comments. You can replace `stats.linregress` by `polyfit`, no problem. The tricky part is more to determine `indNZ`; the for-loop is just to select the appropriate ranges, do the linear fit and plot the result. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Cleb. This is not exactly what I am looking for (for my exact data), but it is a good start.  Sorry for deleting this post and reposting it.  I thought I would be able to reach more people if I posted again.  I didn't realize how unfair that was, again, very sorry for this.  I am going to accept your answer because it did work very well for the data set that I provided, and it also gave me an idea to try.  Thank you!

Comment: @PiccolMan: Ok, no worries; just felt a bit weird to invest some time in it and then get deleted without giving an actual reason... With the other data set it might be a bit tricky since it can be represented quite well with just one linear fit, I think. Maybe you can post it as a separate question using this one as reference and explain your expected outcome in more detail (with at least some code sample)!? In the example here it is quite clear why you want three different linear regressions; for the updated data set it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try that if I'm not able to figure it out myself.