# Fit step wise linear data via python using curve fitting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-regression, curve-fitting

I have some [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yU7o4C5oZAIeYD_CIlW9dc9I78t48DC1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116548792032000328887&rtpof=true&sd=true) on planetary radii and mass, that shows some piece wise linearity. I tried to fit the curve like this,

```py
    file = pd.read_excel('Mass - Radius Relation.xlsx')
    mass = file['Me']
    radius = file['Re']

    x1 = []
    y1 = []


    x2 = []
    y2 = []


    x3 = []
    y3 = []


    for i in range (0, np.size(radius)):
        if radius[i] <=1.3:  #radius[i] <= 0.4 and 
            x1.append(np.log(radius)[i])
            y1.append(np.log(mass)[i])

      
        if radius[i] >= 1.3 and radius[i] <= 11:# and mass[i] <=500: # and mass[i] >= 0.001:
            x2.append(np.log(radius)[i])
            y2.append(np.log(mass)[i])

    
        if radius[i] >= 11:# and radius[i] <= 11:
            x3.append(np.log(radius)[i])
            y3.append(np.log(mass)[i])

        
    def model1(x1, m1, c1):
        return m1*x1 + c1

    param_bounds=([-np.inf, -np.inf],[np.inf, np.inf])
    fit1 = curve_fit(model1, x1, y1, bounds = param_bounds, absolute_sigma=True, method = 'trf')

    def model2(x2, m2, c2):
        return m2*x2 + c2

    param_bounds=([-np.inf, -np.inf],[np.inf, np.inf])
    fit2 = curve_fit(model2, x2, y2, bounds = param_bounds, absolute_sigma=True, method = 'trf')

    def model3(x3, m3, c3):
        return m3*x3 + c3

    param_bounds=([-np.inf, -np.inf],[np.inf, np.inf])
    fit3 = curve_fit(model3, x3, y3, bounds = param_bounds, absolute_sigma=True, method = 'trf')

    ans1,cov1 = fit1
    fit_m1, fit_c1 = ans1
    fit_sm1, fit_sc1 = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov1))

    # print the fit results:
    print("m1 : %.6f +/- %.6f"%(fit_m1, fit_sm1))
    print("c1 : %.6f +/- %.6f"%(fit_c1, fit_sc1))

    ans2,cov2 = fit2
    fit_m2, fit_c2 = ans2
    fit_sm2, fit_sc2 = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov2))

    # print the fit results:
    print("m2 : %.6f +/- %.6f"%(fit_m2, fit_sm2))
    print("c2 : %.6f +/- %.6f"%(fit_c2, fit_sc2))

    ans3,cov3 = fit3
    fit_m3, fit_c3 = ans3
    fit_sm3, fit_sc3 = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov3))

    # print the fit results:
    print("m3 : %.6f +/- %.6f"%(fit_m3, fit_sm3))
    print("c3 : %.6f +/- %.6f"%(fit_c3, fit_sc3))

    plt.errorbar(np.log(radius),np.log(mass), fmt='ko', mfc = 'white',markersize=5, zorder = 1)

    newx = np.linspace(min(x1),max(x1),1000)
    plt.plot(newx, model1(newx,fit_m1,fit_c1), zorder = 2, c='r', linewidth = 3)

    newx2 = np.linspace(min(x2),max(x2),1000)
    plt.plot(newx2, model2(newx2,fit_m2,fit_c2), zorder = 3, c='g', linewidth = 3)

    newx3 = np.linspace(min(x3),max(x3),1000)
    plt.plot(newx3, model3(newx3,fit_m3,fit_c3), zorder = 3, c='b', linewidth = 3)
```

And this is what I got,

[image]

No doubt it seems correct !! but ideally, it looks like this,

[image]

In general, I want to fit the curve that looks like this, through any function or any method via python.

Comment: In the last graph the line bends back, so it is not an `y(x)`. You'd need a parametric curve.

Comment: @mikuszefski So what will be the formula or method for it? I'm quite new to this kind of curve fitting can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Well, standard curve fitting assumes some `y = f(x)` with errors on `y` only. If I get it right, you are more looking for a path through a cloud. In this sense it is more a orthogonal distance regression ODR. I'd probably write my own residual function and fit the start and end point of the middle segment put two directions for the end segments. You'd need to figure how to handle the point-to-line distance, especially the case where a point has reasonable distance to two segments. There might be a fancy method in `scikit` but I am not into this.

Comment: I gave [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35712200/1534017) on a related problem a while back; not sure if it is of help here, though...